# Strange variable assignment using read

Tags: bash

I'm using bash in the WSL (via Terminus) and I'm trying to read in a csv file using the following:

```
INPUT=student_lookup.csv
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read st1 st2
do
    fsrc1="./test_rep/*$st1*.org" ;
    fsrc1=${fsrc1,,}
    fsrc2="./test_rep/*$st2*.org" ;
    fsrc2=${fsrc2,,}
    echo "$fsrc1"
    echo "$fsrc2"
done < $INPUT
```

The problem is my output looks like:

```
./test_rep/*AAABBB001*.org
*.orgt_rep/*AAACCC002
./test_rep/*BBBCCC002*.org
*.orgt_rep/*BBBDDD003
```

The first variable assignment is happening as expected, but I'm confused as to why the second variable is overwriting the start of the variable rather than appending `*.org` to the end? I'm reading in student numbers (I've changed the letters of the student numbers, but the format is the same).

My input file looks like

```
1  AAABBB001,AAACCC002
 1 BBBCCC002,BBBDDD003
 2 CCCDDD003,CCCEEE004
```

Edit: seems like the dos line endings were the problem
I resolved it by stripping the first 9 letters from the read line, i.e.

```
fsrc2="./test_rep/*${st2:0:9}*.org" ;
```

Comment: Does your input file have Windows style line endings and you're on a unixish system?

Comment: I'm using the WSL bash via Terminus, I shall add it to my question

Comment: Your input file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: Please include a sample of the input file.

Comment: So that's probably the case, then.

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious now that you mention it. Fixed :)